# how to upgrade drupal 7 site to universal analytics

Tags: google-analytics

what happens if a user upgrades to universal analytics on their google analytics admin page, yet we are still using the drupal 1.4 module, which according to the documentation does not support universal analytics

Comment: Is there a reason not to upgrade to the Google Analytics 2.0 module?

Comment: well because we only do upgrades of modules to production every few months  .  So I want to know what happens in the meantime until our next scheduled code upgrade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that there will be no effect in the meantime on the existing google analytics behaviour, just that the new UA functionality will not be available.